# OneNote page pushed to the top left and the font becomes really small

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I did something to a page in my OneNote 2013 desktop application, and then I found out later that it made the page looks really small in OneNote Android app:

[image]

Looks like the text box is pushed to the top left of the screen and the font becomes really small.

I suspect there is something on the bottom right, but didn't find anything.

The page looks normal on the desktop application.

How do I update this page to look normal on the android app like the other pages?